# mysql multiple query with multiple statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query which returns the usernames of my downlines and order them on the basis of (users who referred more downlines)
This is query.

```
SELECT user_name FROM users u 
WHERE referby='$competitionmaker'
ORDER BY (select count(p.user_id) from users p where u.user_name=p.referby) 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

It works fine. But the thing I want.
I want to select the downline usernames of only those who have referred more than 5 peoples. How can I do it?
can I use this?

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user_name from users u where referby='$usern' AND
(select count(p.user_id) from users p where u.user_name=p.referby)>0 ORDER BY
(select count(p.user_id) from users p where u.user_name=p.referby) DESC LIMIT 10")
```

or is there any other idea?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your data model...you have a users table with the same user repeated for each 'referby' entry?  That doesn't seem right...you will have to describe your table layout better here

Comment: You are looking for the having clause: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp